# How to average two (or multiple histograms) with R

Tags: r, plot, statistics, histogram, mean

**Could someone tell me how to average two histograms with R?**

I came across the *HistogramTools* package and the `AddHistograms` function:

```
h1<-hist(na.omit(a[,1]),breaks = 100,plot=F)
h2<-hist(na.omit(a[,2]),breaks = 100,plot=F)
> AddHistograms(h1,h2)
Error in .AddManyHistograms(x, main = main) : 
  Histograms must have identical breakpoints for this operation.
```

but I always have the same **error** `Histograms must have identical breakpoints for this operation`? can someone explain why?
I am guessing is that **a[,1] and a[,2] are not the same length**, same with the outputs of h1 and h2 (i.e. **I don't have the same length for "breaks","mids","counts" between h1 and h2**).

Could you tell me how to average my two histograms using this function or anything else with R?

Comment: Maybe you can try `hist(c(a[,1],a[,2]))`, but without a reproducible example it's hard to tell. You should also specify what you intend by "average two histograms".

Comment: Could you please provide some data?  Did you try to set an identical vector of breakpoints `VectorOfBreakpoints <- c(0, ..., ..)` to each histogram, like `breaks = VectorOfBreakpoints`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps below:

1. Create `h1` and `h2`,
2. combine and sort the breaks vectors,
3. keep the unique values
4. and add the histograms.

With the (not reproducible) example in the question,

```
h1 <- hist(na.omit(a[,1]), plot = FALSE)
h2 <- hist(na.omit(a[,2]), plot = FALSE)

brks <- sort(c(h1$breaks, h2$breaks))
brks <- unique(brks)

h1 <- hist(na.omit(a[,1]), breaks = brks, plot = FALSE)
h2 <- hist(na.omit(a[,2]), breaks = brks, plot = FALSE)

h12 <- AddHistograms(h1, h2)
plot(h12)
```

Note also that `na.omit` is not really needed, `hist` will discard them anyhow.